# How to make a read only field with an incremental number?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, read-only

I need to make a field that increases by 1 with every new item in a sharepoint list.
And also make it a read-only field.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't an out-of-the-box `ID` field enough? It's read only, starts from 1 and is incremented by 1 every time you add an item. It's available in the views as well.

If you need the number to decrement when items are removed, then develop an event receiver which would assign `SPList.ItemCount` to a read only column.

This probably won't be used, but still:

```
<Field ID="{347B2202-146B-4ADB-8847-C4EB8996A837}"
    Type="Text"
    Name="ReadOnly_ID"
    StaticName="ReadOnly_ID"
    DisplayName="ID"
    Description=""
    Group="Custom Columns"
    ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
    DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
    ReadOnly="TRUE" />
```

Then add an event receiver (make sure the `ListTemplateId` is correct). You can use `ItemAdding` instead of `ItemAdded` - probably would be even better (as you would save the farm from resource-hungry little sucker `SPListItem.Update()`

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="10111">
     <Receiver>
        <Name>ReadOnlyIDItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>YourNamespace.ReadOnlyIDItemAdded</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Override `ItemAdded` method:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ReadOnlyIDItemAdded : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);

            var currentList = properties.List;
            var currentItem = properties.ListItem;
            currentItem["ReadOnly_ID"] = currentList.ItemCount;

            base.EventFiringEnabled = false; //In case you have another event receiver attached
            currentItem.SystemUpdate(false);
            base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Or `ItemAdding`:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.AfterProperties["ReadOnly_ID"] = properties.List.ItemCount;
    //You might need to increment that by 1 as the ItemCount might not be increased by 1 at that time.
}
```

Comment: that does not work when you delete an item

Comment: Why does it need to work when you delete an item? Should it decrement by 1? As far as I can tell from the requirement "increases by 1 with every new item" the ID field is more than enough.

Comment: I think OP is already known with this info "increment by 1". No it should not decrement by 1! I just tried to put this info that you have inserted 5 items... then deleted 2..... If you add an item now, what will be the ID? I liked your question **Should it decrement by 1?**. Nope it should not!

Comment: The decrement part is there because for some people, there cannot be a break in continuity, so an event receiver would have to be used to account for that if desired.

Comment: I agree with EricAlexander. But  @PaulStrupeikis became angry with my first comment and then he edited!

Comment: No no, Atish, I am never angry, I am just simply grumpy. All the time :) I just explained why I though the ID would work perfectly as the continuity isn't a requirement. Peace. Btw, I edited the answer again. Twice. And I edited this comment as well. Sorry.